# How do I get an image to stretch out a DIV

Tags: css

I am trying to get an image to stretch out a div element in my new Tumblr blog theme.

Currently my photo div is sizing to the full width of its parent container. The problem I have is that I also have a captions div below the photo and if the photo is not the full width of its containing div I dont want the captions to spill past the edges of the photo.

[The Problem !](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/973862/test/index.html)

This is what I am after:
[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/973862/problem.jpg](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/973862/problem.jpg)
[Here is a drawing !](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/973862/problem.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>untitled</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="TextMate http://macromates.com/">
    <meta name="author" content="Brant Winter">
    <!-- Date: 2009-04-26 -->
</head>

<style type="text/css">

.container {
    width: 520px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.photo {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


</style>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="http://8.media.tumblr.com/mFYIJY2I7mpit79h73TC9xa7o1_400.jpg">
    <div class="caption">Sausage dog airtime</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is what it looks like in my browser:
[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/973862/Picture%202.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/973862/Picture%202.png)
[This is what it looks like](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/973862/Picture%202.png)

The container div should be centered, the image should be centered within that and the caption text should not be allowed to go past the edges of the photo ( if there was enough text to do so )

Not sure if I am making any sense, but any help would be appreciated - I have spent hours on this today !!!

Comment: If you tried to post images for what the page should look like, we can't see them.

Comment: I would rephrase the title/question. It sounds more like what you want is for the text div to shrink to the width of your photo.

Comment: Did you finally achieved what you want ? Can you please pick an answer that worked (or tell us what you did in the end). Thx

Answer (score 0):

You mean like centering the photo?

```
.photo {
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
text-align:center; <--- 
}
```

Comment: Nah - its more about centering in a div ) because that is what I have to work with in Tumblr, and then making sure my caption div does not extend out past the border of the photo. see: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/973862/test/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would just to be to fix the width of the container. Why is it `520px`?

If it has to be `520px`, though, then just center the stuff in the container and add auto-margins for the caption:

```
<style type="text/css">

.container {
    width: 520px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.photo {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.caption {
    max-width: 333px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

</style>
```

The `max-width` property, in particular, will prevent the caption from spilling past the edges of the photo.

Comment: Its 520px because that is what is needed to fit in around my Tumblr theme. I mainly use 500px wide images, but every now and again I need to post a smaller width image, say like the sausage dog, I cant really used fixed width divs because I cant accommodate for all images. I would like to have the text contained under the image and not go past the edges of the image.

Comment: Actually - that fixes it !!!!!

Damm - I spent hours trying to get this to work. I'll see what happens when I put the code in the actual theme code, but for now - it works !

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/973862/test/index2.html

Comment: Oh - actually, I see why it is working. The max-width attribute. You see, this will stop say a 500px image from having the text extend out to the edges of the bigger image.

Comment: Yeah, that's the best way I can think of. Of course, the max-width is still hard coded, and I'm not sure if there's a way to get around that issue. Still, I hope this helps.

Comment: hmmm - I wonder if I could rewrite the css on the fly with qjuery. Then I could set the max-width attribute based on image width.

Comment: Is max-width supported on IE6? Quirksmode only lists it as "minimal".

Comment: Well, people shouldn't be using IE anyway. ;) In all seriousness, though, there are workarounds for IE6's lack of a max-width attribute, easily found via Google. They look pretty ugly, though. Oh, and rewriting the CSS on-the-fly via JavaScript might work—interesting idea.

Comment: About to go flying, but i'll post back tonight with my solution !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using jQuery to resize it, you could try something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".container").css("width", $(".photo img").css("width"));
        });
    </script>
```

That finds the width of the image inside the div (note the space between ".photo" and "img") with class "photo" and applies that width to the div with class "container". Just to be safe, you'll probably want to use IDs if possible, but this will work as long as the class names are unique.